# How can I select min row index from dataframe?

Tags: r, indexing, min

I have below data frame and I want to get the minimum row index 
on certain conditions

```
collect_date         a     b 
--------------------------
2018-09-04 14:00     1     1
2018-09-04 15:00     1     1
2018-09-04 16:00     1     1
2018-09-05 17:00     1     1
2018-09-05 18:00     1     1
2018-09-05 01:00     1     0
2018-09-05 02:00     1     0
```

and I want to select the lowest row minimum index number when 2018-09-05 & b==0? 
I tried min(which(....)) but it doesn't match what I want to get.
How can I do it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `which.max(df$collect_date == "2018-09-05" & df$b == 0)` ?

Answer (score 0):

The "index" is the position in the array and differs from the names of the rows and columns. Your solution depends on "row.names" and "names" and does not return an index. A safer way to do this (particularly on large arrays) would be:

( df <- data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10)) )

## Return min col index

```
  which.min(apply(df,MARGIN=2,min))
```

## Return min row index

```
  which.min(apply(df,MARGIN=1,min))
```

If you then wanted the associated column or row name you can use this index with names() or rownames().

## Column name with minimum value

```
names(df)[which.min(apply(df,MARGIN=2,min))]
```

## Row name with minimum value

```
rownames(df)[which.min(apply(df,MARGIN=1,min))]
```

Comment: Hey, you can use `** WORD **` instead of `# WORD` to make it "big".

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want #6 as an output,

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread("collect_date    a     b 
        2018-09-04      1     1
        2018-09-04      1     1
        2018-09-04      1     1
        2018-09-05      1     1
        2018-09-05      1     1
        2018-09-05      1     0
        2018-09-05      1     0") 
df <- as.data.frame(df)
```

This would give you what you want,

```
min(which(df$collect_date == "2018-09-05" & df$b == 0))
```

Or as @Ronak Shah  mentioned,

```
which.max(df$collect_date == "2018-09-05" & df$b == 0)
```

will give you the same answer

Comment: sorry i changed problem .. collect date have data & time information .. then i tried this solution but got weird .. could you test on changed problem ?

Comment: With the addition of time, when reading you have a new column. Try to create a new data.frame that takes `as.POSIXct(paste(df[, 1], df[, 2]))`, then apply the same procedure.